# How to install ShinyApp server on Cpanel

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Hosting with Cpanel (linux interface of my host).
I want to load my ShinyApp and R codes to run on it. Can you help me about it?
I don't know whether I need both R server and Shiny server or just shinyApp server.